# Unable to edit/delete correct item into Section list view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have the view below which has a list of tasks with completed/incomplete sections but when trying to edit one of the items of the list, the last item of the section is always selected and the delete is not even allowed. It looks when testing that all records inside the section are one single record so the delete slide doesn't work and when editing it get the last record. Below the complete code so you can try to help me identify where the issue is.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

struct ListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Task.taskList(),animation: .default) private var items: FetchedResults<Task>
    
    @State var isAddFormPresented: Bool = false
    
    @State var taskToEdit: Task?
    
    init(predicate: NSPredicate?, sortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Task>(entityName: Task.entity().name ?? "Task")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        
        if let predicate = predicate {
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        }
        _items = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let data = groupedEntries(self.items)
        
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            
            if data.isEmpty {
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image("empty")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.pink, lineWidth: 2))
                
                Spacer()
                
            } else {
                
                List {
                    
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { (section: [Task]) in
                        
                        Section(header: Text(section[0].isComplete == false ? "Incomplete" : "Completed")
                                    .font(.body)
                                    .foregroundColor(section[0].isComplete == false ? Color.pink : Color.green)
                        ){
                            
                            self.completedView(section: section)
                            
                        }
                        .sheet(item: $taskToEdit, onDismiss: {
                            self.taskToEdit = nil
                        }) { task in
                            TaskFormView(
                                taskToEdit: task,
                                name: task.name!,
                                taskDetails: task.taskDetails ?? "",
                                important: TaskType2(rawValue: task.important ?? "") ?? .none,
                                urgent: TaskType(rawValue: task.urgent ?? "") ?? .none,
                                secondaryCategory: Category(rawValue: task.secondaryCategory ?? "") ?? .other,
                                isComplete: task.isComplete,
                                dateAdded: task.dateAdded ?? Date()
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: addTapped) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            .shadow(radius: 20)
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing, 40)
                    .padding(.bottom, 24)
                    .accentColor(Color(UIColor.systemRed))
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemYellow).opacity(0.5))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .sheet(isPresented: $isAddFormPresented) {
            
            TaskFormView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
    
    func groupedEntries(_ result : FetchedResults<Task>) -> [[Task]] {
        
        return Dictionary(grouping: result) { (element : Task) in
            
            element.isComplete
        }
        .values.sorted() { $0[0].dateAdded! < $1[0].dateAdded! }
    }
    
    func completedView(section: [Task]) -> some View {
        
        ForEach(section, id: \.id) { task in
            
            Button(action: {
                
                taskToEdit = task
                
            }) {
                HStack {
                    
                    CategoryRowView(category: Category(rawValue: task.secondaryCategory!)!, dateAdded: task.dateAdded!)
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        
                        HStack {
                            
                            if task.isComplete != false {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(.pink)
                                    .padding(.top, 10)
                                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                            }
                            Text(task.name!)
                                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                .padding(.top, 10)
                                .padding(.leading, 5)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        
                        HStack {
                            
                            Image(systemName: "tag.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            Text(task.important == "none" ? "Not Important" : "Important")
                                .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .padding(.vertical)
                            Text(task.urgent == "none" ? "Not Urgent" : "Urgent")
                                .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .padding(.vertical)
                        }
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing, 2)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(height: 140)
                .background(Color(.systemBackground))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(color: .black, radius: 4, x: 0, y: 0)
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
            }
        }
        .onDelete { row in
            deleteEntry(row: row, in: section)
        }
    }
    
    func addTapped() {
        
        isAddFormPresented.toggle()
    }
    
    private func onReturnTapped() {
        
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
    
    func deleteEntry(row: IndexSet, in section: [Task]) {
        
        let task = section[row.first!]
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [task.id!.uuidString])
        
        viewContext.delete(task)
        
        do {
            
            try viewContext.save()
            
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM"
    
    return formatter
}()
```

[image: print screen of the list view]

Comment: Can you print to the console the row and section in the onDelete modifier? I get the feeling that modifier is in the incorrect position.

Comment: I can't because I can't even slide the record to activate the onDelete to delete the record.

Comment: You code is far from a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the grouping in the body is quite inefficient, why not just use an `NSFetchedResultsController` directly and have CoreData do all the grouping/sorting work. Also, your `onDelete` seems to be on the section not the row so you would be getting info on the section not the tasks/row move it up

Comment: Sorry for not being reproducible but I shared exactly the code that I'm handling. I don't know how could I use the NSFetchedResultsController on this case and the onDelete is right into the ForEach that build the row.

Comment: I was created a watered down version of what you have and you are missing a `List` the swipe for deleting does not appear without a `List`

Comment: I don't understand when you say there are no `List`, it's before the section `ForEach`, did you mean I should have another `List` inside the `func completedView` before the `ForEach`  related to the task row ?

Thanks for the code below, I'm evaluating how can I implement it since there are searches and filters associated with this view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your `View` so you can see how a `NSFetchedResultsController` would do the work. You need a `List` to be able to swipe a row to delete.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
class TaskListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.previewAware()
    @Published var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Task>?
    
    init() {
        setupController()
    }
    func setupController() {
        do{
            fetchedResultsController = try retrieveFetchedController(sortDescriptors: nil, predicate: nil, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Task.isComplete))
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    func deleteObject(object: Task) {
        persistenceController.container.viewContext.delete(object)
        save()
    }
    func save() {
        do {
            if persistenceController.container.viewContext.hasChanges{
                try persistenceController.container.viewContext.save()
                objectWillChange.send()
            }else{
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
//MARK: FetchedResultsController setup
extension TaskListViewModel{
    func retrieveFetchedController(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?, sectionNameKeyPath: String) throws -> NSFetchedResultsController<Task> {
        
        return try initFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath)
    }
    private func initFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?, sectionNameKeyPath: String) throws -> NSFetchedResultsController<Task> {
        fetchedResultsController = getFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath)
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
            return fetchedResultsController!
            
        } catch {
            print( error)
            throw error
        }
    }
    func getFetchedResultsController(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?, sectionNameKeyPath: String) -> NSFetchedResultsController<Task> {
        
        return NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: getEntityFetchRequest(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate), managedObjectContext: persistenceController.container.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath, cacheName: nil)
    }
    private func getEntityFetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?, predicate: NSPredicate?) -> NSFetchRequest<Task>
    {
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        if sortDescriptors != nil{
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
        }else{
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Task.dateAdded), ascending: false)]
        }
        if predicate != nil{
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        }
        return fetchRequest
    }
}
struct TaskListView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: TaskListViewModel = TaskListViewModel()
    @State var taskToEdit: Task?
    var body: some View {
        if vm.fetchedResultsController?.sections != nil{
            List{
                ForEach(0..<vm.fetchedResultsController!.sections!.count){idx in
                    let section = vm.fetchedResultsController!.sections![idx]

                    TaskListSectionView(objects: section.objects as? [Task] ?? [], taskToEdit: $taskToEdit, sectionName: section.name).environmentObject(vm)
                    
                }
            }.sheet(item: $taskToEdit, onDismiss: {
                vm.save()
            }){editingTask in
                TaskEditView(task: editingTask)
            }
            
        }else{
            Image(systemName: "empty")
        }
    }
}

struct TaskEditView: View {
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    var body: some View {
        TextField("name", text: $task.name.bound)
    }
}
struct TaskListSectionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: TaskListViewModel
    let objects: [Task]
    @State var deleteAlert: Alert = Alert(title: Text("test"))
    @State var presentAlert: Bool = false
    @Binding var taskToEdit: Task?
    var sectionName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text(sectionName) , content: { ForEach(objects, id: \.self){obj in
            let task = obj as Task
            Button(action: {
                taskToEdit = task
            }, label: {
                Text(task.name ?? "no name")
            })
            .listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
            
            
        }.onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        })
        
    }
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            deleteAlert = Alert(title: Text("Sure you want to delete?"), primaryButton: Alert.Button.destructive(Text("yes"), action: {
                let objs = offsets.map { objects[$0] }
                
                for obj in objs{
                    
                    vm.deleteObject(object: obj)
                }
                //Because the objects in the sections aren't being directly observed
                vm.objectWillChange.send()
                
            }), secondaryButton: Alert.Button.cancel())
            
            
            self.presentAlert = true
            
        }
    }
}

struct TaskListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            TaskListView()
        }
    }
}
```